# tmux: inner window notify outer session

Tags: tmux

Inside a tmux session I nest another tmux session, on a remote computer.
I was wondering if there is a way for the inner tmux to notify the outer when a process is completed.

In both (remote, local) .tmux.conf I ve set:

```
set-option -g visual-activity off
```

I know that it may sounds impossible but I was wondering whether there are any plugins that do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can always, at the end of your process, send the special "alert" or bell character, eg with

```
$ echo -en '\a'
```

and this should make the outer tmux session window beep or flash if you configure your terminal for a visible bell.
On the inner tmux you might need to have the bell propagated with

```
set-option bell-on-alert on
```